# What are those ._<name> files?

Tags: uti

I downloaded a Java library and noticed, that for every file and directory there is a binary file of the form `._<name>`. It contains something like:

> "Mac OS X ... com.apple.quarantine ... com.google.Chrome"

Have those files been added by an Mac OS X IDE (I'm an Ubuntu user planning to use the library with Eclipse)? Can I safely remove those files?

TIA for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those are extended attribute files, which OSX uses when the filesystem doesn't support resource forks or extended attributes.  You don't care about them.  (The entry you quoted is a message to the Finder to display a "This file was downloaded at (date).  Downloaded programs may be unsafe.  Do you want to open it?" dialog along with a button which will open Chrome and take you to the page the file was downloaded from.)

Comment: While the attributes these files (technically "[AppleDouble](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleDouble)" files) are generally unnecessary, there are a few cases where they are actually important.  Alias files are an example that comes to mind -- without the type code, they won't even be recognized as aliases.

Comment: But on Ubuntu, they're not going to be recognized anyway.  (See the original question.)

Comment: agreed, as long as the files will be used on the Ubuntu system (where things like aliases wouldn't work anyway).  If they were going Mac -> Ubuntu -> Mac, then the AppleDoubles might matter.